# replacingOccurrences works in Playground, fails in compiled macos app

Tags: swift, macos, backslash

I am sending a POST request to a server and get a response back. So far so good. When I convert the data to a (very long) string the response contains backslashes, which shouldn't be there.

“

Here is the snippet that handles the request:

```
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let response = response, let data = data {
            print(response)               
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            let replaced = str?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
            print(replaced)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Trying to replace the '\' character with

let replaced = str?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "")

works in the Playground, however a debug runtime it does not strip the backward slashes.

Question: Is there a bug in Xcode? In 2018 with Xcode 9 there was such a bug. I am using Xcode 11.3 on macOS 10.14 compiling a macOS app.

Second  question, is there another way to decode the data than using

```
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Thanks

Comment: "Second question, is there another way to decode the data than using" well, is your response simple `.utf8` encoded String? If that's the case, your current solution is fine.

Comment: Do if `let replaced2 = replaced { print("Replaced2: \(replaced2)"}`. I think it might be because of optional (and that's just a print in console, not the same if you render it in a label/uitextview. So do a proper unwrap.

Comment: Are you sure the string contains **real** backslashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to decode data, not encode.

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let response = response, let data = data {
            print(response)                        
            let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            print (str)


        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because `str` is not an optional, no? Would you test with this `let str = String(decoding: dataTest, as: UTF8.self); let str2 = String(data: dataTest, encoding: .utf8); let str3 = String(data: dataTest, encoding: .utf8)!` you'll see. Giving your output would have been good. And it's only in console.